# Laravel 5.3 - How can I debug artisan migrate:reset? Getting `unexpected ')' `

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

1) Run

```
php artisan migrate
```

2) Result

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'
```

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake in one of your migrations.

Comment: Thanks @Mihailo, that helped me alot. There was a mistake in one of the migrations.

Comment: Oh cool, glad I could help out :)

Answer (score -1):

```
It may be Syntax error in your migration files
check you all migration fiels.

for example:
 <?php

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateLikesTable extends Migration{                                       
   public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('likes');
})'----->here is error of ending braces
});---->>>here also its throughs an error

so please check your braces in your migration files
```